# PHP tutorials/guides that influenced you or improved your code

Tags: php

What tutorials or guides about features/techniques influenced the way you did something.

Eg a compelling tutorial ([located here](http://example.com/unittestingwithphp)) about unit testing got you into unit testing. Your code improved dramatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think some of the most important "documentation" that helped me improve some parts of my code / coding are :

- documentations from Frameworks / libraries, and the source code of some of those : they showed me how useful it is to have a well-presented well-structured well-commented well-organized code.

  - About those, I could say the manual and sources of MVC Frameworks tend to show great stuff, sometimes *(inheritance, interfaces, design patterns, ... things you only hear about at school -- or at least it was the case when I was at school ^^ )*
- code reviews / peer reviews at work

  - both when my code was under review : advices from more experienced colleagues are always great, when you're willing to learn
  - and when I am the one reviewing code : you always learn new stuff when reading other's people code, and being able to discuss about it really is great !
- The community : I read (even if often quite only rapidly) lots of blog-posts, and those are often written by people with lots of experience, who want to share great stuff

  - One nice source of those, for PHP of course, is [Planet PHP](http://www.planet-php.net/) ; just subscribe to the RSS feed ^^
  - But there are plenty more, not only about PHP !
- Conferences are also a nice way to meet people, discuss with them, and learn from them

Comment: Good suggestions. I think I have most of them implemented. Learned a ton from looking at the Zend Framework code.

Answer (score 7):

The most influential document that I have used for PHP is manual [itself](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php).  Call me old fashioned.

Comment: I agree, the manual is a good source.